# Cannot create flutter project in android studio

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

"Flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart.exe" is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file.

Comment: You can use Android Studio widget to create new project too.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like dart.exe isn't installed correctly. First try reinstalling flutter sdk and restarting your computer. If it still doesn't work, make sure the path "Flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/" directory is part of your [PATH variable](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the dart.exe got delete somehow, so it worked after I got the file back to where it suppose to be.